# ESlint problem with Cypress while using Vite

Tags: vue.js, cypress, eslint, vite

I wanted to try automated testing with Vue3 for my next project.
When I created my app using Vite and selected that I would like to test with Cypress everything seems to work fine but...

Although project starts like it suppose to when i type in console `npm run lint` I receive an error message saying:

`C:\Users\myname\Desktop\vue-project\cypress\support\component.js`

`27:1  error  'Cypress' is not defined  no-undef`

and this is the line in which error occurs:
`Cypress.Commands.add("mount", mount);`

Any help from you guys would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
env: {
  node: true,
  "cypress/globals": true,
}
```

to my `eslintrc.cjs` default export removed the eslint issues from cypress for me.

Comment: Glad to know someone else encountered this also :D
Useful answer btw, thanks :)

Comment: I had similar problem with standard Vite/Vue3 starter project. Eslint complained that cypress.config.js "require" was not defined in that files line 1. Eslint also complained that module was not defined in that same file's line 3.
Adding Matt's suggestion above fixed the errors.
project started with standard npm init vite@latest

Vite: 4.3.4
Cypress: 12.11.0
Eslint: 8.39.0
Eslint-Plugin-Cypress: 2.13.3

Answer (score 0):

Ok so maybe someone will find it helpful.
It appears that problem with this one considers mainly ESlint.

If you can not run Cypress with command `npm run test:unit`:

1. make sure Cypress is also installed globally.
2. Then simply ignore ESlint errors considering cypress and don't change this line - `const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");` even if lint suggest
   doing it.

Congrats, you now should be able to run tests with Cypress :)

Bonus: if you do mind errors in your console and wanna keep it clean you search for some lint setup considering Cypress,  to find a good setup for your lint if you do mind errors in your console.'eslint-plugin-cypress' didn't do the trick for me.